# wxPython panel now showing colour

Tags: python, wxpython, panel, frame, wxwidgets

I am writing an application in wxPython, when i go to run the application i expect to see 2 different colored panels but i dont. 
Can someone tell me why ?

```
import wx



class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Frame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.Center()
        self.Show()

        panel1 = Panel1(self,-1,size=(200,200),pos=(0,0))
        panel2 = Panel2(self,-1,size=(200,200),pos=(210,0))        



class Panel1(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Panel1,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.SetBackgroundColour("PURPLE")

class Panel2(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Panel2,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.SetBackgroundColour("RED")        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    Frame(None,title="MY_PROJECT",size=(500,600))
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import wx



class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Frame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.Center()


        panel1 = Panel1(self,-1,size=(200,200),pos=(0,0))
        panel2 = Panel2(self,-1,size=(200,200),pos=(210,0))        

        self.Show()

class Panel1(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Panel1,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.SetBackgroundColour("PURPLE")

class Panel2(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Panel2,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.SetBackgroundColour("RED")        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    Frame(None,title="MY_PROJECT",size=(500,600))
    app.MainLoop()
```

Try with above code.